# MapReduce job with HAR file output

Tags: java, mapreduce, hdfs, har

I have multiple small input files. For running a map reduce job with a multiple input files, this will be the command:

```
hadoop jar <jarname> <packagename.classname> <input_dir> <output>
```

But if in case the above <output> is just a text file and should be a `HAR` file what will be the command such that all the output of the MapReduce job is a HAR archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MapReduce job that you execute in your example can't write its output directly to a har file.  Instead, you can run `hadoop archive` as a post-processing step after your MapReduce job to pack the MapReduce job output into a har file.

```
> hadoop jar */share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar wordcount /README.txt /wordcountout

> hdfs dfs -ls /wordcountout
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 chris supergroup          0 2015-12-16 11:28 /wordcountout/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 chris supergroup       1306 2015-12-16 11:28 /wordcountout/part-r-00000

> hadoop archive -archiveName wordcountout.har -p /wordcountout /archiveout

> hdfs dfs -ls har:///archiveout/wordcountout.har
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 chris supergroup          0 2015-12-16 12:17 har:///archiveout/wordcountout.har/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 chris supergroup       1306 2015-12-16 12:17 har:///archiveout/wordcountout.har/part-r-00000
```

You may optionally delete the original contents (the `/wordcountout` directory in my example) if having the data in har format alone is sufficient for your needs.

Additional information about the `hadoop archive` command is available here:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-archives/HadoopArchives.html

Comment: Hi @ChrisNauroth thanks for the response, so there is no way of specifying the output of the MapReduce job as `HAR`?

Comment: @JamesCarlNecio, no, there is no way to specify the output as going directly to har.  Part of the difficulty is that it would be impossible for multiple concurrent reduce tasks to write to the same har file.  The standard solution is to run `hadoop archive` as a post-processing step.

Comment: Ok thanks, will set your answer as the solution to my question.